# Connecting to an existing database (on a HDFS) from Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a database on HDFS (Hadoop filesystem) along with a schema file.

I'm trying to connect to this existing database from hive.

Any pointer are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by database, but using the [External Table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables) feature of Hive, this is fairly easy. You'll need 3 things: a location to the data, and Input(Output)Format to read (write) your data (rows), and potentially a a SerDe to interpret your data (columns). If you need to keep your Hive Schema and external schema in sync, there isn't really a good way to do it out of the box. You'll have to write some custom code that monitors the source schema and modifies the Hive schema on a schema change. Though non-trivial, it's also fairly easy to do this.